# Haskell Typeconstraints

Tags: haskell, type-constraints

Why do I have to write the Typconstraints like this for Fractional:

```
isItTwo' :: (Eq a, Fractional a) => a -> Bool   
isItTwo' 2 = True  
isItTwo' _ = False
```

but for Integral:

```
isItTwo :: Integral a => a -> Bool  
isItTwo 2 = True  
isItTwo _ = False
```

shouldnt Integral as a Typeclass not also need to be in Eq ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haskell numeric type classes like `Integral` and `Fractional` are a bit weird, sometimes.

In this case, it so happens that the `Integral` type class is a subclass of `Real`, which is a subclass of `Ord`, which is a subclass of `Eq`. Hence, the `Integral a` constraint subsumes `Real a, Ord a, Eq a`, and there's no need to add those.

By contrast, `Fractional` is a subclass of `Num`, and that is not a subclass of `Eq`, so `Eq` must be added manually.

The rationale is not so easy to guess, but I would say that the `Fractional` and `Num` type classes allow types that can not be equated. Perhaps one might want to use something like `Integer -> Bool` to represent the binary digits of some real number, and this can not easily be compared (or printed). After all, `Fractional` only requires `fromRational`, so we can't convert a fractional type into a rational and compare it.

Instead, `Integral` subsumes `Real`, which requires `toRational`, so these types must be comparable. It makes sense to add `Eq` as a superclass, since comparison must be possible anyway.

Comment: Okay, I also got to this point, but with the same logic applied Fractional is a Subclass of Num, which is a subclass of Eq. So why?

Comment: @Neeliy Num is not a subclass of Eq. Perhaps many years ago it was (I can't remember), but now it is not. (I'm not defending this design choice, only stating the facts. :-) )

Comment: You are absolut right in Zvon Num is a Subclass of Eq, in Hoogle not. So i guess Zvon its out dated. Thanks :)